# How to get __reactInternalInstance (React Component) from selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I am writing integration tests with selenium `web driver, Mocha and Chai` where I want to use Enzyme for fetching the elements of react component.

when I do `driver.findElement(By.xpath('//div[@id="root"]/*[1]'))`, I get the root element but I am unable to get the `__reactInternalInstance` which is there in the dom properties of the root element.

I tried doing `getAttribute('_react instace id')` but  I am not getting this.
By using `driver.executeScript()` I am getting this value but it gives me `maximum overstack` error as it is a big object with lots of dependencies.

[image]